# What else can be used instead of an API Key to protect resources in a REST API as is implied by OWASP?

Tags: session-management, rest, owasp

I was reading the [OWASP Cheat Sheet Series](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/index.html), specifically their cheat sheet for REST Security and one of the points they had under the section for [API Keys](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#api-keys) was:

> Do not rely exclusively on API keys to protect sensitive, critical or high-value resources.

What are the alternatives to protect resources via a REST API that they are indicating towards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the alternatives to protect resources via a REST API that
> they are indicating towards?

They are indicating to implement further measures in addition to API keys, not to look for alternatives.
The other measures are in the **Table of the content** on right of the same [page](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html).

[image]

Comment: D’oh! I thought they meant something other than that. Guess my interpretation of that was wrong.